# Unable to prevent auto line spacing in html/css wit the <h1> tags

Tags: html, css

With my  tags I am trying to stop it from auto creating a line space.

```
<h1>Title</h1>
```

Here is my current css rule.

```
h1
{
    font-family: Blackadder ITC;
    text-align: left;
}
```

And in my body rule I have this

```
body
{
    text-align: center;
}
```

When I add this to my css h1 rule

```
display: inline;
```

It does prevent the h1 tags from automatically creating a line space but then it overrides the:

```
text-align: left;
```

rule, therefore the text centers in the middle of the page, and I don't want that.

Is there a way to make the text go in the left hand side of the page, as well as to prevent it from creating automatic line spacing?

Comment: line-height? margins? padding?....

Comment: I have got non of that.

Comment: @JoeSmith add your code

Comment: @JoeSmith if you have none of that (explicitly), then the browser's default take over. Which means you have all of that.  Add your code so we can check

Comment: Sure I will give it to you.

HTML

`
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 <head>
  <title>Title</title>

  <link href="Main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

 </head>

 <body>

  <h1>Title</h1>
  <a href="#" class="button">Button 1</a>
`

CSS

`
h1
{
 font-family: Blackadder ITC;
 display: inline;
 text-align: left;
}

body
{
 text-align: center;
}

.button
{
 background-color: alpha;
 border-width: thin;
 border-style: groove;
 border-color: alpha;
}
`

Answer (score 0):

You can just go ahead and remove the margin on the `<h1>`.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto 0;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Blackadder ITC;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  border-width: thin;
  border-style: groove;
  border-color: alpha;
  margin: 3px 0;
}
.paragraph {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-family: calibri;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Website Title</title>

  <link href="Main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <a href="#" class="button">Button 1</a>
  </nav>

  <br/>

  <div class="paragraph">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>
      Information
    </p>
  </div>




</body>

</html>
```

EDIT: I had given previously given the solution to reduce the line spacing (which is the space between two lines) on the `h1` element. I guess you wanted both the `h1` and the button on the same line, which was not clear in the question. 
To have your two elements in the same line, you can either make use of positioning (like I have done above), or make use of floats after setting the display of `h1` to `inline`.

Comment: Sorry man I copped what you did and they still does nothing, still the same issue mate :(

Comment: Can you give us a link to your code (codepen etc) so that we can see what's actually happening?

Comment: Hey Rocks

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IvUiP5fPPYLpehSVQLlZq4czWogONNfJ/view?usp=sharing

Here is the link to my website

Thanks for the help :)

Also is there a reason why my blue element is not fully stretching the width in my website?

Comment: @JoeSmith I have edited my answer. Regarding your other question, the `body` comes with its default margin. You can remove that to make the element stretch the entire screen (also consider using CSS resets). You can also play around with `line-height` on your h1 element, if you want to further reduce the gap.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your help so much :) This fixed the blue element issue and now it stretches all the way, But the h1 problem though, when I use the `line-height`, it cuts the top of heading which is not what I am after. I want to put button 1 in the exact same place as the heading. For example this website https://www.letsnurture.com. Do you know what I should do?

Comment: Ah. I see what you wanted now. I have edited the answer one more time. From next time, please make sure you mention what you want correctly in the question. Screenshots will also help.